# php запрос по нажатию кнопки и редирект

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

сделал sql запрос по нажатию кнопки следующим образом:

```
echo '<form action = "" method = "post" target = "_self">
      <tr><td><input type="text" name="Name_format" /></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Добавить" /></td></tr></table></form>';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$Name_format=$_POST['Name_format'];
$sql= "INSERT INTO in_format (name_format) VALUES ('$Name_format')";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

И в принципе это работает, но есть две проблемы:
1. Делает запрос не только при нажатии кнопки, но и при обновлении страницы, соответственно постоянно заносит в бд либо пустое поле, либо значение предыдущего запроса.
2. Как сделать после нажатия кнопки еще и обновление страницы?

Пытался делать редирект на саму себя

```
header('Location: program_format.php');
```

Но localhost бесконечно выполняет переадресацию=(
Спасибо за внимание=)

Comment: дак вы куда этот редирект-то вставили? надо обработку `POST` сделать в начале страницы до вывода формы и прочего, в этом же if-е сделать и редирект

Answer (score 0):

Работает следующим образом, спасибо @teran =)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$new_Name_format=$_POST['Name_format'];
$sql= "INSERT INTO ineum_archive_format (name_format) VALUES ('$new_Name_format')";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
header('Location: program_format.php');


echo '<form action = "" method = "post" target = "_self">
      <tr><td><input type="text" name="Name_format" /></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Добавить" /></td></tr></table></form>';
```